# i try this solution to convert a binary number to a sentence"Aren't bonfires fun!?" but before this sentence appears 'undefined'. How can remove this?

Tags: javascript, binary

```js
function binaryAgent(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  var digit = [];
  var newStr;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    digit.push(parseInt(arr[i], 2));
  }

  for (let j = 0; j < digit.length; j++) {
    newStr += String.fromCharCode(digit[j]);
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(
  binaryAgent(
    '01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111',
  ),
);
```

> output:'undefinedAren't bonfires fun!?'
>
> expect output:'Aren't bonfires fun!?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to initialize `newStr` to an empty string

```js
function binaryAgent(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ');
  var digit = [];
  var newStr = ''; // <-- Here
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    digit.push(parseInt(arr[i], 2));
  }

  for (let j = 0; j < digit.length; j++) {
    newStr += String.fromCharCode(digit[j]);
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(
  binaryAgent(
    '01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111',
  ),
);
```